# Using Integer And Char Pointers in C++ or C?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
int *ab = (int *)5656;
cout << *ab; //Here appcrash.


int *ab;
*ab = 5656;
cout << *ab; //These block crashes the app too.
```

But i can get the hex value of content of pointer if i write this:

```
int *ab = (int *)5656;
cout << ab; //Output is hex value of 5656.
```

So i want to ask: * is a operator that brings the contents of pointer(?) but why in this(these) example(s) app crashes?

And i can use that operator if i change code into this:

```
int a = 5656;
int *aptr = &a;
cout << *aptr; //No crash.
```

---

And why dereference operator(*) brings the only first character of a char:

```
char *cptr = "this is a test";
cout << *cptr; // Here output = 't'
cout << cptr; // Here output = 'this is a test'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int *ab = (int *)5656;
cout << *ab; //Here appcrash.
```

In this case, you are setting the pointer `ab` to point at the address 5656. Do you know what's at this address? No you don't. You are telling the compiler to trust you that there is an `int` there. Then, when you dereference the pointer with `*ab`, you obviously find that there isn't an `int` there and you get undefined behaviour. In this case, your program crashes.

```
int *ab;
*ab = 5656;
cout << *ab;
```

In this case, you have an uninitialised pointer `ab` which you then dereference to assign 5656 to the `int` it points at. Since it's uninitialised, dereferencing it gives you undefined behaviour. Think of it this way. You haven't put an addres in `ab` so you don't know where it points. You can't just dereference it and hope it points at an `int`.

```
int a = 5656;
int *aptr = &a;
cout << *aptr;
```

This is fine because you know you have an `int` object with value 5656 and you know that `aptr` contains the address of that `int` object. It's perfectly fine to dereference `aptr`.

```
const char *cptr = "this is a test";
cout << *cptr; // Here output = 't'
cout << cptr;
```

(Your code was using a deprecated conversion to `char*`, so I changed it to a `const char*`.)

The string literal `"this is a test"` gives you an array containing `const char`s. However, it then undergoes array-to-pointer conversion giving you a pointer to its first element. Since each element is a `const char`, the pointer you get is a `const char*`. You then store this pointer in `cptr`.

So `cptr` points at the first element of the string. Dereferencing that pointer gives you that first element, which is just the first character of the string. So you output `t`.

The I/O library has special overloads that take `const char*`s and treat it as pointing to a string of characters. If it didn't, `cout << cptr` would just print out the address in `cptr`. Instead, these special overloads will print out the null-terminated array of characters that `cptr` is assumed to point to.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you can find if there is an integer. You can only find if somewhere is accessible memory. Each accessible memory can be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth noting that the application crashes you are observing are due to the fact that it is very unlikely that your process (i.e. program) owns the memory at the location you specify: 5656.

Modern operating systems disallow access to memory allocated by other processes.

Imagine what a headache it would be if that we're not the case: one program could modify the data associated with another one!

The "access violation" message is a helpful hint that you're accessing memory that your process does not own.

Comment: I tried to give reputation but stackoverflow does not allow. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Oh , since now i'am banned from StackOverflow(Can not ask new question because i got a lot of bad reputation for my questions).


 But i have another question: http://notepad.cc/share/czDBmKv7sJ

Answer (score 0):

- is a operator that brings the contents of pointer(?)

No. * is a operator that brings the contents of memory which pointer point to.

Here:

```
int *ab = (int *)5656;
cout << *ab; //Here appcrash.
```

Pointer `ab` contains 5656. `*ab` tries to access memory which pointer `ab` point to => `*ab` tries to access memory at address 5656. Your program is not allowed to access memory at address 5656 because it is not allocated or read-only => app crashes.

- And i can use that operator if i change code into this:
  int a = 5656; int *aptr = &a; cout << *aptr; //No crash.

Here you allocate and initialize memory: `int a = 5656;`
Here you write address of previously allocated memory to pointer: `int *aptr = &a;`
Here you access memory which was previously allocated: `*aptr` (memory contains 5656).
You have right to access it => app doesn't crash.

- And why dereference operator(*) brings the only first character of a char

Because `char` is not string, `char` is *character*. When you dereference pointer to char, you get char.
C has no built-in type for string. That's why it's common to use pointer to memory containing string. This pointer usually points to a first character of string: `char *` - pointer to character

Comment: Thanks for answer,
But if app do not have rights to access another memory block which was allocated by another app, how this code block runs well: http://notepad.cc/share/czDBmKv7sJ

Comment: Yes, you are right. App has rights to access memory allocated by another app. App crashes when it tries to access unallocated or read-only memory. I'll edit my answer. But anyway the only way to safely avoid crashes is accessing memory which was allocated by your program.